# What do we want in our HTML5 outline?

Tags: html

A lot of sites use the `<nav>` element for menus (naturally). If you have a heading like a `h2` for instance this heading appears in the site's HTML5 outline. Often a heading for a menu isn't very informative for what the site is about, like if it says "Min menu".

How do you do it? Which parts of a webpage do you want to show up in the HTML5 outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the parts that are important to the content! When setting up up the HTML5 outline, leave out all those online-gimmicks (banner rotation, menus, …) and concentrate on finding a good markup for your site main content. Everything else is just decoration. Or the other way around – think of a print-out of your webpage and consider to identify those parts of your page that you don't need on paper.

To the menu/headline topic: A menu should never ever have a single headline in it. There is simply no content for such a headline. (A list of links on the same site is hardly content but more like a glossary.)

Comment: Thanks for a good answer feeela. So in my case I hav a menu inside a <nav> tag and a heading to that menu which I feel is necessary for the visitor. Shall I use a <span> on the heading instead of h2 to hide it from the outline?

Comment: Why not a `p`? Or a combination of `p > strong` which gives that label a little bit more importance – but not that important like a headline. Please stop using `span`s and `div`s if there is an alternative (which `p` is in most cases). The ultimate tag would be `label`, but that is allowed in forms only. (Though in was discussed for early HTML5/XHTML2 drafts to use that tag on a broader base.)

Comment: Ok, now I get an Untitled Section for the <nav> element, is it better to use a <div> instead to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Why is this a problem? Who says so?

Comment: This article http://html5doctor.com/outlines/ says: "For accessibility reasons, we recommend each sectioning element have a heading, even <aside> and <nav>, as shown below. If you don’t want these headings to be visible, you can always hide them with CSS." But I really don't want to hide it.

Comment: @RascalCapac - Quite honestly, the HTML5 outline algorithm is so broken, and so unimplemented, that it's not worth wasting time on. See the thread starting [here, for current thinking on the matter](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2014May/0004.html). But if you want to hide the nav section from the document outline, wrap it in a sectioning root object. `<figure>` is quite convenient.